# Libgdx and server game

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I wish to create a multiplayer card game but with a server side.
I develop on Libgdx (android) for visual.

I succes to connect my application with Google Play Service because i think i can use the google play account for create the information i need for my game in the server. Like number of victory, number of defeat...

I 'm really confused because I feel wrong. Should I continue with google or create my own login and create an account on my server directly with socket ?

Thank you very much
(and sorry for my english)

Comment: Check out Unity Software: http://unity3d.com/es

Answer (score 1):

You should, if you can, take advantage of the Google Play infrastructure for tracking the state of your game server.  It should solve a lot of problems for you (especially identifying users reliably) vs rolling your own infrastructure.

One downside of the Google Play infrastructure is that it only works on Android devices (so if your Libgdx app also runs on other platforms, those will need a different solution).

Google Play infrastructure also assumes that your Android clients can talk to each other and can push simple state (like win/loss values and saved game state) to the Google servers or between each other.  I don't think there is any support for running real server-side code with Google Play infrastructure (though you may be able to leverage the sign-on, at least).

Have you seen the Libgdx documentation and code tutorials here:  https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Google-Play-Game-Services-in-LibGDX

Comment: Ok, thx for your reply. I don't really need other platform that Android. I don't find where i can collect information about the user connected in Google Play Service, so i can't link with a own server. Yes i have see your link, and realy help for user connexion but it's just a game with leaderboard and achievment implantation.

Comment: If you want to run your own server-side logic, you might be able to (ab)use the web API and talk to the same sessions as your android clients: https://developers.google.com/games/services/web/api/turnBasedMatches.  You'll need to be more specific about what you're trying to do though.

Comment: The turn based matches is really good but i don't understand how to do a side server. I want to do a card game 1vs1 player. But the player bet something and when the game is finish, someone loose the bet and the other take it. But i need a server for prevent against piracy...